# Cannot add the TextBox Handler in C# (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create textboxes dynamically:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    TextBox1 = new TextBox();

    TextBox1.ID = "TextBox1";
    TextBox1.Style["Position"] = "Absolute";
    TextBox1.Style["Top"] = "25px";
    TextBox1.Style["Left"] = "100px";          
    form1.Controls.Add(TextBox1);
```

Above works fine, but when I want to add a handler to this:

```
TextBox1.Click+=new EventHandler(MyFunction)
```

intelisense does not recognize the click event and a message says:

System.WebUI.WebControls.Textbox does not contain a definition for 'Click'.

Any ideas on how to fix this is appreciated

Comment: Because `TextBox` doesn't have Click event, and the message is saying about it.

Comment: Yes see my comments below..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the documentation for the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx it does not have an `Click` event at all (and when you think about it, that would be evil: you don't want a postback every time someone clicks on a textbox).

Why do you want to handle someone clicking on a textbox?

Comment: Haha, lack of sleep , I totally forgot that Textbox does not have a click event.
I'm using LinkButtons in fact so I should be fine.